# Entity Framework Core generates wrong query for MySQL when I use separate IQueryable generic method

Tags: entity-framework-core

I faced with a strange behaviour when entity framework core throwing away my Includes.
I need to make some generic methods to filter and combine my queries and those methods must receive some parameters and IQueryable filter subquery and return combined IQueryable result for further composition.
I simplified my code and made an example when you can see what I do mean:

```
public IQueryable<Tuple<TResult, TFilter>> Method1<TResult, TFilter>(IQueryable<TFilter> filters)
   where TResult : ResultEntity
   where TFilter : FilterEntity
{
    var q = from state in _dbContext.Set<TResult>()
            join f in filters on state.ID_Result equals f.ID
            where ....
            select new Tuple<TResult, TFilter>(state, f);
            
    return q;
}

public void GetResult(int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    IQueryable<Car> results = _dbContext.Cars.Include(x => x.Images);
    
    // 1) All right, it has the images
    var q1 = Method1<CarState, Car>(results).ToList();
    
    // 2) Wrong, there is no images. And SQL query doesn't contain any joins to Images table
    var q2 = Method1<CarState, Car>(results).Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    
    // 3) Without the method and with anonymous type it's ok.
    var tmp = from state in _dbContext.Set<CarState>()
              join f in results on state.ID_Result equals f.ID
              where ....
              select new { state, f };
    var q3 = tmp.Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Builder methods or constructors if you want to use query later. It is because LINQ translator cannot trace back fields to generate correct SQL.

This part of query is problematic

```
new Tuple<TResult, TFilter>(state, f);
```

Better to create new class(es)

```
public class MTuple<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; set; }
}
```

And use them in your methods (similar to anonymous classes usage)

```
public IQueryable<MTuple<TResult, TFilter>> Method1<TResult, TFilter>(IQueryable<TFilter> filters)
   where TResult : ResultEntity
   where TFilter : FilterEntity
{
    var q = from state in _dbContext.Set<TResult>()
            join f in filters on state.ID_Result equals f.ID
            where ....
            select new MTuple<TResult, TFilter>
            {
               Item1 = state, 
               Item2 = f
            };
            
    return q;
}
```

**SUGGESTION**

Such classes can be generated by [T4 template](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/13ee1af9b612ccac7ce7a5ca7ee1382b8cbfcdd0/Source/LinqToDB/Common/Internal/MutableTuple.tt), or just copy [generated code](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/blob/13ee1af9b612ccac7ce7a5ca7ee1382b8cbfcdd0/Source/LinqToDB/Common/Internal/MutableTuple.generated.cs)

Comment: Thank you! I tried to create my own class instead of tuples with the same result.
How can I solve my problem without query chaining and code duplication? I have tens of similar queries

Comment: I didn't get whole problem. But maybe you are looking for such https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/pull/127 use case. I have crated PR for LINQKit for simplifying reusable method creation. Still not merged, but you can compile it by yourself it is a small library.